# How to merge two data columns and show it as one column?

Tags: postgresql

In sum1 the data has stopped coming and is replaced with sum2. I want the previous data from sum1 and merge with the new value of sum2. Below is the query but not working.

```
SELECT 
time AS "time",
CASE WHEN (data->>'sum1') in (data->>'sum1')::numeric END as "" or
CASE WHEN (data->>'sum2')='' 
THEN NULL ELSE (data->>'sum2')::numeric END as ""
FROM data WHERE  id = 68 AND
time > $__timeFrom()AND  time < $__timeTo() ORDER BY 1,2
```

Comment: Are sum1 and sum2 ever going to both have data at the same time? Or will each row only contain one or the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want  something like this:

```
SELECT time AS "time",
       CASE 
          WHEN data ? 'sum1' then (data->>'sum1')::numeric 
          ELSE (data->>'sum2')::numeric 
       END as "sum"
FROM data 
WHERE id = 68 
  AND time > $__timeFrom()
  AND time < $__timeTo() 
ORDER BY 1,2
```

If the key `sum1` exists in the `data` column, then use the value from that, else use the value from the key `sum2` .

Another option is to use `coalesce()` to pick the first non-null value:

```
coalesce((data->>'sum1')::numeric, (data->>'sum2')::numeric) as "sum"
```

Both solutions assume that there will never be a value where both keys exists.

Comment: I use coalesce feature and it worked perfectly fine. Thank You